# How to decrement values in Batch? (CLOSED)

Tags: batch-file, decrement

So, I've been trying to make a classic "Three Doors" game in batch, but I came across a problem. Apparently it's very hard to decrement values in batch? Does anyone have any idea of what I could do? I put my main loop of the game under this text.
Is there any way I could do the decrementing efficiently and compactly? Thanks! I put blockquotes around the location of the error.

```
    :loopdeloop
    color 07
    set /a num=%random% %%3 +1
    SET /p door=Pick a number between one and three: 
    if %door% EQU %num% (
    color 0a
    @echo Correct!
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
    SET /a score+=1
    )
    if %door% NEQ %num% (
    color 0c
    @echo Incorrect!
```

> SET /a score-=1

```
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
    cls
    @echo Three Doors.
    @echo Behind two of these doors there are ghosts.
    @echo Behind one, there is freedom.
    @echo Which one will you take?
    title Three Doors - Score: %score%
    goto :loopdeloop
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses for your second `IF` command.  Your `IF` commands are creating a parenthesized code block.  Any time you need to reference a variable inside a code block you need to use delayed expansion.  https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 1):

The two independent if's following one another IMO don't make sense.
Use an else clause instead. ( And use proper indenting)

```
:loopdeloop
color 07
set /a num=%random% %%3 +1
SET /p door=Pick a number between one and three: 
if %door% EQU %num% (
    color 0a
    @echo Correct!
    SET /a score+=1
) else (
    color 0c
    @echo Incorrect!
    SET /a score-=1
)
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
cls
@echo Three Doors.
@echo Behind two of these doors there are ghosts.
@echo Behind one, there is freedom.
@echo Which one will you take?
title Three Doors - Score: %score%
goto :loopdeloop
```

Comment: Okay, fixed that, now, to the question I was asking, how do I decrement values in Batch scripting? I want to decrease "score" by one if %door% is not equal to %num%

Comment: You already used the syntax `SET /a score+=1` to increment.  What do you think does `SET /a score-=1`do?